# NextJS: Redux store is returning empty when calling the store from another page either client-side or server-side

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I am calling a list of data in a page on the server-side, which is going to redux store. I want this data to be available to other pages.

Now, I have another page where I want to edit an article on the client-side. I am fetching a random article (for testing only) from the previously populated redux store with `useSelector()`. But the store is returning empty for this page! How come the populated store is not available in this page?

For testing, I tried with `wrapper.getServerSideProps()` to render the page on the server-side by accessing the store on the server but it's returning empty also!

The page where redux store is populating with blog list:

```
export default function BlogsList({blogs}){
    return(
        <div className="mainCon">
            <ul>
                {blogs.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.author}>
                        <span>{item.author}</span><br/>
                        <span>{item.title}</span>
                        <h4>{item.body_delta}</h4>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}


export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps( async ({store, req}) =>{
    store.dispatch({type: FETCH_BLOG_LIST });
    store.dispatch(END);
    await store.sagaTask.toPromise();

    const myStore = store.getState();
    const blogs = myStore.blogReducer.blog;  
    return { props: {blogs}, };
});
```

The store output:
[image: redux-devtools-screnshot]

This is the client side only page where the store is returning empty:

```
export default function editBlog(){
    const myBlog = useSelector(state => state.blogReducer.blog);
    const body_delta = myBlog[1].body_delta;
    console.log(body_delta);    // Throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'body_delta' of undefined
                                // Since the store is empty here

    return (
        ...
    );
}
```

And this is it's empty store:
[image: redux-devtools screenshot empty-store]

How do I access the store data from this page also?

**Edit:** I added `getInitialProps` in `_app.js` but still the store is empty!

```
class MyApp extends App {
  static getInitialProps = async ({Component, ctx}) => {

      return {
          pageProps: {
              ...(Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx) : {}),
          },
      };

  };

  render() {
      const {Component, pageProps} = this.props;

      return (
          <Component {...pageProps} />
      );
  }
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

Comment: If you want to share state across pages you'll have to move the logic to a [custom `_app` page](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app).

Comment: You are fetch the blog list data in `BlogsList` components. How could you get the data in `editBlog`? If you want to get data in `editBlog`, you should use `wrapper.getServerSideProps` in `editBlog`.